# How to convert CLOB into multiple VARCHAR2 rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a single column (COMMENTS) that is currently a CLOB. Is there a way I can split the COMMENTS CLOB column into separate (4k) VARCHAR2 columns in oracle SQL?

Thanks in advance

Here is my attempt below:

```
create or replace procedure longsubstr(p_rowid in rowid,
                                       comment in comment)
                            return varchar2
                            as l_tmp long;
                            begin
                            select COMMENT into l_tmp from table_name 
                                                     where rowid = p_rowid;
                            return substr(l_tmp, p_form, p_for);
                            end;
                            /
```

Comment: Through a plsql with dynamic code, sure you can. Dynamic because you will need to inject the varchar2 column names into the query. Otherwise if it was just to get the values in a query you could do it in a CTE

Comment: can you show me an example of the code that needs to be written?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an oracle environment here and I'm a little bit rusty on it. Let see if someone else can add an answer. It would be better if you provide any attempt though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83e1dc/3):

```
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( t.comments, 4000, l.COLUMN_VALUE )
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL * 4000 - 3999
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL * 4000 - 3999 <= DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( t.comments )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) l
```

or

```
WITH positions ( comments, pos ) AS (
  SELECT comments,
         1
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT comments,
         pos + 4000
  FROM   positions
  WHERE  pos + 4000 <= DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( comments )
)
SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( comments, 4000, pos ) AS split_comment
FROM   positions
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you be able to explain to me what you did in the first solution? if not I will still mark your answer as the best answer but any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't full understand why you decided to perform a cartesian join with ultimately gets you the value '1' that you use as the column value in the substr function. Can't you just use '1' instead? what benefit is there in cartesian joining to get that value?

Comment: @icerabbit It generates a `VARRAY` populated by a hierarchical query to give the values `1,4001,8001,...` up to the length of each `CLOB` and each of those `VARRAY`s is then correlated to the appropriate row and joined back to the original table and used to get the 4000 character substring starting at that position.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

> `dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte )`
>   *function*

for this :

```
declare
    type typ_comment is table of varchar2(4000);
    v_varchar typ_comment := typ_comment();
    v_clob    table_name.comments%type;
    k         number;
    j         number := 4000;
begin
    select comments into v_clob from table_name where rowid = '&p_rowid'; -- like AAAS9BAAEAAAAEeAAA without quotation
    k := ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(v_clob)/j);
    v_varchar.extend(k); 
  for i in 1..k 
  loop
    v_varchar(i):= dbms_lob.substr( v_clob, j, 1 + j * ( i - 1 ) );
  end loop;
end;
```